# Python type hint for class member with None type or dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, type-hinting, python-typing

I have class member which is either `None` or a `dict`.
I have a method for the lengths of that member that returns `None` if the
member is `None` or the size of the dictionary if it exists:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, a: bool = False) -> None:
        self.has_a = a
        self.prop_a = {"a" : 1} if a else None

    def length_prop(self) -> int:
        length_prop = None
        if self.has_a:
            length_prop = len(self.prop_a)
        return length_prop
```

If I check the typing with `mypy`:

```
test.py:10: error: Argument 1 to "len" has incompatible type "Optional[Dict[str, int]]"; expected "Sized"
                length_prop = len(self.prop_a)
                                  ^
test.py:11: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Optional[int]", expected "int")
            return length_prop
```

Very understandable, since it does not know if `self.prop_a` is really `dict`.
How can I design my code to get around this and get the right typing?

Comment: `has_a` seems redundant. `prop_a` encodes all the necessary information already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. **`mypy` can't and shouldn't infer the relationship between `has_a` and `prop_a` across the functions.** You need to include an explicit check for `None` inside the `length_prop` function. This error is not spurious -- for example, what happens if some external code modifies the value of `has_a` but not `prop_a`?

   The simplest solution is to do away with the `has_a` field, since all the information it encodes can be retrieved using a check on `prop_a` (for example, `prop_a is not None`) instead.
2. **The return value of `length_prop` can be `None`**, so use `Optional[int]` rather than `int` for the `length_prop` method.

The following code snippet resolves both of these issues. `mypy` does not find any errors in this class definition:

```py
from typing import Optional

class A:
    def __init__(self, a: bool = False) -> None:
        self.prop_a = {"a" : 1} if a else None

    def length_prop(self) -> Optional[int]:
        length_prop = None
        if self.prop_a is not None:
            length_prop = len(self.prop_a)
        return length_prop
```

Comment: That was what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.10, you can use `Dict[str, int]| None`, otherwise you can use `Union[Dict[str, int], None]`

Also you'll need to check if the object is not None to return a proper value (maybe raise an exception or return a negative value)

Comment: `Optional[...]` is the standard "abbreviation" for `Union[..., None]`.

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers the question. The issue is about an incompatible type in a call to `len()`, not the syntax for the union of multiple types.